# Печать отчёта из XML

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services

Доброго времени суток.

У меня сложилась следующая задача: необходимо сформировать отчёт и вывести его на печать из XML файла. Задействованы должны быть не все поля. Можно использовать любые расширения для генерации отчётов. Просмотрев приличное количество статей, я не пришёл к нормальному выводу, как это можно реализовать. Прошу помощи у Вас. Заранее спасибо.

Пример XML:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: странно, что вы, прочитав достаточное количество статей, так и не попробовали написать, хоть одно, пусть и не очень правильно работающее решение, это раз, а во вторых, отчеты - понятие достаточно растяжимое

Comment: @Sublihim, я не смог найти нужного мне ответа. Я находил с Report Viewer - не могу понять, как создавать шаблон отчёта по XML. Находил с Crystal Reports - остались огромные пробелы, ввиду разной информации по данному поводу на разных ресурсах

Comment: посмотрите, к примеру сюда: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-reports-from-xml-documents-using-reportviewer/. Я уверен, можно еще много примеров использования накопать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047278/generating-report-from-rdlc-xml-string

Answer (score 0):

Для создания отчета можно воспользоваться `FixedDocument`, если вы будете писать программу на базе `WPF`

В XAML

```
<DocumentViewer>
    <FixedDocument x:Name="fixedDocument">

    </FixedDocument>
</DocumentViewer>
```

А в коде уже создаем содержание

```
/// <summary>
    /// Отображение отчета в окне
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="books"></param>
    public void LoadBooksDocument(ICollection<Book> books)
    {
        //окно документа
        DocumentWindow docWindow = new DocumentWindow();

        //каркас документа
        var pageContent = new PageContent();
        docWindow.fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);
        //размер соответствует A4(Width:8.267 Inches, Height=11.692 Inches) при dpi=96
        var page = new FixedPage() { Width = 96 * 8.267, Height = 96 * 11.692 };
        pageContent.Child = page;

        //содержимое
        page.Children.Add(GetHeaderContent());
        page.Children.Add(GetDataContent(books));

        //показываем окно с документом
        docWindow.Show();
    }

/// <summary>
    /// Заголовок документа
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private UIElement GetHeaderContent()
    {
        TextBlock text = new TextBlock()
        {
            FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Segoe UI"),
            FontSize = 34,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        text.Inlines.Add(new Run("К Н И Г И"));
        FixedPage.SetLeft(text, 96 * 0.75);
        FixedPage.SetTop(text, 96 * 0.75);

        return text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Содержимое на основе списка книг
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="books"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private UIElement GetDataContent(ICollection<Book> books)
    {
        ListView listView = new ListView() { Width = 96 * 6.5, Height = 96 * 9 };
        GridView gridView = new GridView();

        GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc1.Header = "Id";
        gvc1.Width = 96 * 0.5;
        gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("BookId");
        gridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);

        GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc2.Header = "Автор";
        gvc2.Width = 96 * 2;
        gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Author");
        gridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);

        GridViewColumn gvc3 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc3.Header = "Название";
        gvc3.Width = 96 * 3.7;
        gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Title");
        gridView.Columns.Add(gvc3);

        listView.ItemsSource = books;
        listView.View = gridView;

        FixedPage.SetLeft(listView, 96 * 0.5);
        FixedPage.SetTop(listView, 96 * 1.75);

        return listView;

    }
```

Подробнее посмотреть можете скачав [проект](https://yadi.sk/d/P5-XVleE35mqxp), который я набросал на скорую руку.